# Richtextbox does not display properly

Tags: vb.net

I use this code to load rtf file to RichTextBox, it opens when I used microsoft word but displays some codes when I load it to RichTextBox

```
 *Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\test.rtf")
                RichTextBox1.Text = text*
~~~~
The following error is what I see. How can I correct it?


{\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Calibri;}{\f1 Comic Sans MS;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0 ;\red128\green0\blue128 ;\red255\green0\blue0 ;}{\*\defchp \fs22}{\*\listoverridetable}{\stylesheet {\ql\fs22 Normal;}{\*\cs1\fs22 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*\cs2\sbasedon1\fs22 Line Number;}{\*\cs3\ul\fs22\cf1 Hyperlink;}{\*\ts4\tsrowd\fs22\ql\trautofit1\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Normal Table;}{\*\ts5\tsrowd\sbasedon4\fs22\ql\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10\trautofit1\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Table Simple 1;}}\nouicompat\splytwnine\htmautsp\sectd\pard\plain\ql\fs22\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs22\cf2 gaba}\f1\fs22\cf2\par\pard\plain\ql\f1\fs22\cf2\par\pard\plain\ql{\i\f1\fs22\cf2 ddss}\i\f1\fs22\cf2\par\pard\plain\ql\i\f1\fs22\cf2\par\pard\plain\ql{\i\f1\fs22\cf1 Pronoun[p]}\i\f1\fs22\cf1\par\pard\plain\ql\i\f1\fs22\cf1\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs22\cf2 go}\f1\fs22\cf2\par\pard\plain\ql\f1\fs22\cf2\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs22\cf3 ddsd}\f1\fs22\cf3\par\pard\plain\ql\f1\fs22\cf3\par\pard\plain\ql{\f1\fs22\cf4 dsds}\f1\fs22\cf4\par\pard\plain\ql\f1\fs22\cf4\par\pard\plain\ql\f1\fs22\cf4\par}
```

Comment: That is not an error, that is rich text code. The `Text` property expects you to give it normal text, not RTF-formatted such. Change `RichTextBox1.Text` to `RichTextBox1.Rtf`.

Comment: You are using the wrong property. Use RichTextBox1.RTF instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you read an HTML file as text and then put the result into the `Text` property of a control, would you be surprised to see the HTML markup?  I would hope not, so why should you be surprised when the same thing happens with RTF?  If you had read about the `RichTextBox` control, which you should have but clearly haven't, then you would know that the `Text` property is just the plain text while the `Rtf` property contains the markup.  You could set the `Rtf` property but the more appropriate way, which further reading would have shown, would be to call the [`LoadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of the control.  It lets you specify whether the file is plain text or RTF.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mixed things up I intended using LoadFile separate and then ReadAllText separate. Thanks all the same.